# Unknown (corrupt memory) error. sprintf_s output.c

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, dll, macros

```
#define DebugPrint(x, y) \
{ \
    char *MACROmsg; \
    char *MACROprint; \
    MACROmsg = (char *) malloc (1056); \
    MACROprint = (char *) malloc (1056); \
    sprintf_s(MACROmsg, 1056, "%ws", x); \
    sprintf_s(MACROprint, 1056, MACROmsg, y); \
    MessageBox(NULL, MACROprint, NULL, NULL); \
    if(MACROprint) free(MACROprint); \
    if(MACROmsg) free(MACROmsg); \
}

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, DWORD dwReason, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    BOOL bRtn;

    DebugPrint(L"%d\t%ws(0x%08X, 0x%08X, %i, \"%ws\")\0", (2, L"a", 4, 4, 4, L"a"));
    DebugPrint(L"%d\t%s(0x%08X, 0x%08X, %i, \"%s\")\0", (2, "a", 4, 4, 4, "a"));

    ...
```

Hello. I am sorry for asking a question because of frustration but I've looked through my code and changed it to start with this. The first line executes fine, the second doesn't. It appears as the second %s has a problem inside output.c (Microsoft's code for sprintf.) A pointer become null. I will consider their code to be perfect and the fault lies with mine but I cannot see it.

I highly doubt that I have managed to change the code of that file and accidently re-compiled it as it is locked and I would have a message warning me.

The DLL is being called from a C++ .net application. I can't imagine the fault being here either.

I have several global variables, if initalized they are only initalized as NULL. They are not referenced. I'm quite frustrated to say the least and I don't know where else to look. Perhaps someone has come across something similiar or has a thought what the problem could or mayeven be.

Thankyou very much.

I'm using Visual C++ 2008.

p.s. The code was different (I wouldn't have normally have considered using sprint_s(..., "%ws", x) but that one was causing errors too. I'm expecting this code to be fine, I just can't figure it. Many thanks.

Comment: I suggest this happens because your parameters in brackets and in macros to printf push only last parameter (see comma operator). Try use variadic macros (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177415.aspx) or inline function.

Comment: I think `PrintData` might be `DebugPrint` but the code refactor for SO has a typo?

In macro `DebugPrint` you should probably check that `malloc()` does *not* return `NULL`

Comment: That is the answer thankyou. :) malloc() was being checked through a debugger. A function is replacing the sprintf but thankyous. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `DebugPrint()` and `PrintData()` are the same I think your problem is that the brackets in `x` will be part of the evaluated macro. I've checked a simple example:

```
#define PRINT(x,y) sprintf(x,y)

PRINT( "%s %d", ("hello",42) );
```

That expands to `sprintf( "%s %d", ("hello",42) )` and so you have a comma operator and only one argument passed so `sprintf()`. Using a variadoc macro should solve that.

Comment: That seems to work fantastic. Thankyou. I don't suppose you know why vswprintf_s doesn't convert a string to a wide-string? (vswprintf_s(v, 20, L"%s", "abc");) I get "abc" not "a\0b\0c\0"

Comment: When printing non-wide-strings in wide-string functions use %S not %s. For example. unsigned char *str; str = "abc"; wprintf("%S", str); is identical to printf("%s", str); and vise-versa.

Answer (score 2):

`(2, L"a", 4, 4, 4, L"a")` is a expression with comma-operators.

The comma-operator evaluates both sides of it and yields the right-hand side.
you have multiple comma's so the total expression there yields `L"a"` .
get rid of the enclosing `()` and it will be ok.

after your edits: I suggest get rid of the define and make it a regular function with `( ,... )` and use `varargs` and pass that varargs to the `vsprint_s` version of `sprintf`.

Comment: It is actualy passed to a function rather than sprintf but I wanted to see and find where exactly the problem was. It was a simple short-cut. :) Thankyou though. :)